# Retaining a counter across multiple rows in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My Data looks like this

```
Person ID, Drug_type, Days_start, Days__end
 1          x        12                30
 1          Y        25                40
 1          z        41                50
 1          v        49                89
```

What im trying to do is create a new variable called line of therapy(LOT) which uses the following logic

```
If row number =1 LOT = 1
If the previous drug day end over laps with the current day start, carry forward the previous LOT value . 
If the days do not overlap take the previous LOT value and add 1.
```

This is how I've approached this so far but keep failing

Step 1: Lag the days start and days end variable

```
group_by(person_ID) %>% mutate(start_lag = lag(days_start)) %>%
  mutate(end_lag = lag(days_end)))
```

This runs fine

Step 2: Add logic so row 1 = LOT  1

```
mutate(lot= ifelse(row_number()==1,0,))
```

Its step 3: where I need to add logic so I have a constant counter that I'm struggling  with

I tried this approach but the output (and logic) are obviously wrong

```
mutate(lot=ifelse(row_number()==1,1,
                       ifelse(end_lag >=days_start, lag(row_number()),
                           ifelse(end_lag < days_start,(row_number()) ,9))))
```

This is unable to count the LOT properly; In SAS we could easily use retain but alas we dont have an equivalent in R (that I'm aware of)

The output I'm trying to get to is this

```
Person ID, Drug_type, Days_start, Days__end  LOT
 1          x        12                30    1
 1          Y        25                40    1
 1          z        41                50    2
 1          v        49                89    2 
 2          a        10                17    1
 2          b        18                20    2
 2         c        26                90    3
```

Comment: can you show the desired LOT for sample?

Comment: Could you also please share your sample data with `dput`? `dput(your_data[1:4, ])` will be nicely copy/pasteable for us. The way you have it now with some commas, some not commas, some underscores, some spaces, etc., is annoying to  import.

Comment: I've edited the question and provided desired output (thanks so much for taking the time to help me on this one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(LOT = cumsum(lag(Days__end, default = -1) < Days_start))
#   Person_ID Drug_type Days_start Days__end LOT
# 1         1        x.         12        30   1
# 2         2        Y,         25        40   1
# 3         3        z.         41        50   2
# 4         4        v.         49        89   2
```

Walk-through:

- `lag(Days__end) < Days_start` tells us if we have any overlap; but
- because `lag(.)` by necessity has nothing for the first entry, we must define a default value; by using `-1` (which I'm inferring is a safe never-to-be-seen value), we're forcing the first `<` comparison to be true; we could also have used `default=-Inf`;
- the `<` comparison produces a `logical` vector (same as the number of rows), and `cumsum` increments the value each time there is a true; in this case, the logical vector is `c(T,F,T,F)` due to: start, overlap, no overlap, overlap, ... and the sum (cumulative or otherwise) of logicals coerces `c(F,T)` to `c(0L,1L)`, which sums up nicely.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Person_ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Drug_type = c("x.", "Y,", "z.", "v."), Days_start = c(12, 25, 41, 49), Days__end = c(30L, 40L, 50L, 89L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works perfectly! Would you mind giving an idiot proof explanation of how this actually works? Its a superb single line

Answer (score 0):

`purrr::accumulate` works well in these situations (although) it can be done in dplyr only.

- `accumulate2` uses two arguments inputs

  - first is `days_start` (..2)
  - second is lagged `days_end` (..3)
- `.init = 0` is also supplied
- function argument is pretty clear (..1 is accumulated value)
- First value supplied through `.init` is finally taken out `[-1]`

```r
df <- structure(list(PersonID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Drug_type = c("x", 
"Y", "z", "v", "a", "b", "c"), Days_start = c(12L, 25L, 41L, 
49L, 10L, 18L, 26L), Days__end = c(30L, 40L, 50L, 89L, 17L, 20L, 
90L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(PersonID) %>%
  mutate(LOT = unlist(accumulate2(Days_start, c(0, Days__end[-n()]), .init = 0, ~if(..2 > ..3) ..1 +1 else ..1)[-1]))

#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#> # Groups:   PersonID [2]
#>   PersonID Drug_type Days_start Days__end   LOT
#>      <int> <chr>          <int>     <int> <dbl>
#> 1        1 x                 12        30     1
#> 2        1 Y                 25        40     1
#> 3        1 z                 41        50     2
#> 4        1 v                 49        89     2
#> 5        2 a                 10        17     1
#> 6        2 b                 18        20     2
#> 7        2 c                 26        90     3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>